# Which font is used when I export formulas from Grapher?

Tags: keynote, font, grapher

You can export formulas from Grapher with drag&drop. Which font is used for this? I want to write some stuff in the same font in Keynote, but I cannot find the correct font...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the default font is **Times**.

If you want, you can also change the equation font in Grapher's preferences. Click on the example equation in the white box under 'Default Font & Size':

[image]